# Fire getData when click on button NOT when key pressed on filters

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am looking for a way of stopping the getData function to trigger when I am typing on the text boxes and instead I want to fire it at will when I click on a button. Does someone know a way to accomplish this?

I know there is a question for this already here , but noone has replied yet and getting an answer would allow to close both the old one and mine.

[AngularJs ng-Table stop getData function when filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208853/angularjs-ng-table-stop-getdata-function-when-filtering)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What *text boxes*?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Sorry, I assumed whoever read the question knew how ng-table works. When you create a table with it, you will assign a filter object for each column. This will make ng-table create a text box on the top of that column so you can filter. I want to cahnge the behaviour so instead of applying the filter on key press, ill add a button and then apply the filter on click.